# Build a variable in a playbook with the hostname and call it in a task

Tags: variables, replace, ansible, hostname

I have a two main variable with subvariables. The main variable `VELABx` and `VELABy` match the `ansible_hostnames`. Following an example of the variables mentioned:

```
VELABx
  location: "text1.1"
  initialism: "text1.2"

VELABy
  location: "text2.1"
  initialism: "text2.2"
```

Now I'd like to run a task which replaces a `regexp` with the `location` variable based on the current `ansible_hostname`. So, I tried this code, but it leads into an error.

```
  - name: Replace location for VELABx
    replace:
      dest: "/path/to/file"
      regexp: 'location'
      replace: "{{ {{ansible_hostname}}.location }}"
    remote_user: rssuser
    become: no
    when: ansible_hostname == "VELABx"
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this? Can anyone bring up a solution?

Comment: As advised in the Frequently Asked Questions of Ansible, moustache do not stack. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names

Answer (score 1):

Things are always easier when you manage to create a proper structure of data. For example, given the dictionaries in a file

```yaml
shell> cat velab.yml
VELABx:
  location: "text1.1"
  initialism: "text1.2"
VELABy:
  location: "text2.1"
  initialism: "text2.2"
```

you can include the data from the file into a dictionary, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: VELABx,VELABy,VELABz
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: velab.yml
        name: velab
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: velab
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  velab:
    VELABx:
      initialism: text1.2
      location: text1.1
    VELABy:
      initialism: text2.2
      location: text2.1
```

The data you provided in the question are not YAML dictionaries. The colon is missing behind the keys. Either fix it, if you can or parse the file. Anyway, create the dictionary whatever is the source.

Then, given the files

```
shell> ssh admin@10.1.0.61 cat /tmp/velab.txt
location
shell> ssh admin@10.1.0.62 cat /tmp/velab.txt
location
shell> ssh admin@10.1.0.63 cat /tmp/velab.txt
location
```

the task to replace the *location* is simple

```yaml
    - name: Replace location for VELAB*
      replace:
        dest: /tmp/velab.txt
        regexp: location
        replace: "{{ velab[inventory_hostname]['location'] }}"
      when: velab[inventory_hostname] is defined
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -CD

PLAY [VELABx,VELABy,VELABz] ******************************************
...
TASK [Replace location for VELAB*] ***********************************
skipping: [VELABz]
--- before: /tmp/velab.txt
+++ after: /tmp/velab.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-location
+text1.1

changed: [VELABx]
--- before: /tmp/velab.txt
+++ after: /tmp/velab.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-location
+text2.1

changed: [VELABy]
```

The next option is to remove the condition and use the default value, instead of skipping the host, when the host is missing in the dictionary

```yaml
    - name: Replace location for VELAB*
      replace:
        dest: /tmp/velab.txt
        regexp: location
        replace: "{{ velab[inventory_hostname]['location']|
                     default(default_location) }}"
      vars:
        default_location: "text99.1"
```

Comment: thanks vladimir for the detailed explanation. that helped a lot! and now my task runs successfully, thanks to you! Regards!

Comment: Hi Vladimir. sry to bother you. when i execute the playbook without the option of skipping the host everything works fine. but with that task i get a fail and the message below (see next comment).

Comment: fatal: [velab170]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute u'velab170'\n\nThe error appears to have been in /development/standalone/ansible/installation/thautest/ve2_thautest_cfg-specific.yml': line 42, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere [...] [WARNING]: Could not create retry file '/development/standalone/ansible/installation/ve2_backup_create_thautest-
cfg.retry'.         [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/development/standalone/ansible/installation
...

Comment: Hi Mr. Green. The error is clear ``'dict object' has no attribute u'velab170'`` Unfortunately, I don't have a crystal ball right now that would reveal the problem. Instead, you'll have to provide [mre] if you want anybody to resolve your problem. You can't do this in comments, of course. See [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work). Either open a new question, I'd recommend it, or [edit] your question and make it [mre].

Answer (score 0):

you must use loopkup, {{}} inside other {{}} is incorrect

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    ansible_hostname: VELABx
    VELABx:
      location: "text1.1"
      initialism: "text1.2"

    VELABy:
      location: "text2.1"
      initialism: "text2.2"

  tasks:

    - name: DEBUG
      debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('vars', ansible_hostname ).location }}"

    - name: Replace location for VELABx
      replace:
        dest: "/path/to/file"
        regexp: 'location'
        replace: "{{ lookup('vars', ansible_hostname ).location }}"
      when: ansible_hostname == "VELABx"
```